# Yii2 Pagination is not working with orderBy

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, yii2

I'm trying to use Yii2 pagination with orderBy but it's not working properly.

Here's my code:

```
$query = Blog::find()->where(['status' => 1])->orderBy('blog_id DESC');
$countQuery = clone $query;
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
$pages->pageSize = 12;
$pages->page = $_GET['page'];
$results = array();
$models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
          ->limit($pages->limit)
        //->orderBy('blog_id DESC')
          ->all();
```

I tried a couple of scenarios but I'm still getting wrong results.

Note: Pagination is working fine without the orderBy but I need it to display the newest items first.

Comment: Can you tell us what results you're expecting and what you're actually getting?

Comment: @GarryWelding New items are missing also the order is not correct

Comment: OK, you said you're expecting newest first, but in your query above I can only see you ordering on blog_id and not any kind of date field...

Comment: I tried to order using the date/time field but I'm facing the same issue so I tried the id field as another solution. that's all

Comment: $query has all the elements?

Comment: Yes, it has all elements.

Comment: Man, still no luck? Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Users::find()->andWhere('UserId > :uid',[':uid' => 1])->orderBy('UserId DESC'),
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 5),
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```